# Iterating over n object of objects using ngFor recursivley

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor

I have an Angular Project where I need to show Folder structures of a Server.
I have json data in this form(demo names):

```
{
    "dirPath": "file:///C:/dev/gallery/filesFromApp/",
    "folderName": "filesFromApp",
    "fileNames": [
        "firmwareUpdate101.txt",
        "keyboard_output.txt",
        "screen-locks.txt"
    ],
    "dirInfoList": [
        {
            "dirPath": "file:///C:/dev/gallery/filesFromApp/Beta1/",
            "folderName": "Beta1",
            "fileNames": [
                "beta1Ubdate.txt"
            ],
            "dirInfoList": []
        },
        {
            "dirPath": "file:///C:/dev/gallery/filesFromApp/Beta2/",
            "folderName": "Beta2",
            "fileNames": [
                "Beta2UPDATE!.txt"
            ],
            "dirInfoList": [
                {
                    "dirPath": "file:///C:/dev/gallery/filesFromApp/Beta2/omaewa/",
                    "folderName": "omaewa",
                    "fileNames": [
                        "nani.txt"
                    ],
                    "dirInfoList": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I need to do is show every Folder in an Angular Material Expansion Panel:

```html
<mat-expansion-panel *ngIf="dirInfos !== undefined">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      {{dirInfos.folderName}}
    </mat-panel-title>
    <mat-panel-description>
      {{dirInfos.dirPath}}
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let dir of dirInfos.dirInfoList">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        {{dir.folderName}}
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        {{dir.dirPath}}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <p *ngFor="let file of dirInfos.fileNames">{{file}}</p>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

[Image to Visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOZ2c.png)

My Problem is that the File structure can go very deep, i.e 25 Folders in. I have no idea how to recursively check this, and then generate the needed HTML, any Ideas? ngFor might be helpful but I am not aware of a way to make this work, even if I use Object.Keys on the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **recursive template design pattern** for your use case. like in [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3512-playing-with-recursive-ng-template-references-in-angular-6-1-10.htm).

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmj9nn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: This really helped! Didn't know this existed, but I added it and adapted it and it works, thanks!

Comment: Glad, I could :)

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate loop by using a `keyvalue` pipe. so you can be able to iterate loop over the object.

so the logic here we implement is the when you have object in json use `keyvalue` pipe when it is array use simple `*ngFor` with out `keyvalue` pipe.

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngIf="dirInfos !== undefined">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      {{dirInfos.folderName}}
    </mat-panel-title>
    <mat-panel-description>
      {{dirInfos.dirPath}}
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let dir of dirInfos.dirInfoList | keyvalue">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        {{dir | json}} 
<!-- HERE YOU WILL GET THE DATA WHICH IS SEPARATED INTO IN TO KEY VALUE PAIR   -->
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        {{dir.dirPath}}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <p *ngFor="let file of dirInfos.fileNames">{{file}}</p>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: This actually read out what I needed, but the second level just printed out json :)

Comment: Yeah bcs for debugging purpose here we use pipe called ‘json’ so you know on which position our required key value is.